# What XLM asset markets allow for greater than 7 decimal places

Tags: assets, trade

I am using lobstr and own Sovereign Gold Bond asset (SGB swisscustody.org). When I trade it says 0.0000000 XLM, but the dollar value of my holdings keeps fluctuating. Lobstr does not allow trading with values more than 7 decimal places. How can I trade the true value of assets? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you only add the trustline or also add funds of said asset?
In general please DYOR **before** interacting with assets as there are many scam assets (especially from the domain you mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

Stellar amount representation uses a fixed 7 decimal digits, this cannot be changed by clients and this is a hard coded limit on stellar. The minimum exchangeable value is 0.0000001, also called a stroop.